# What could cause discordjs/opus encode function error

Tags: node.js, discord.js, buffer, opus

I am new to audio programming. I am using node mic, speaker, and @discordjs/opus packages to build a local real time speaking and listening program, so when I speak to the mic that is connected to my Macbook, I can immediately hear from the speaker of the Macbook.

Below is the relevant section of my nodejs code.

```
const micInstance = mic({
    rate: audioConfig.rate,
    channels: audioConfig.channels,
    bitwidth: audioConfig.bitDepth,
    debug: false,
    exitOnSilence: 6,
});
...
var chunker = new SizeChunker({
    chunkSize: 4096
});
// Create the encoder.
// Specify sampling rate and channel size.
const encoder = new OpusEncoder(44100, 2);
const encoderAAC = new Fdkaac({
    "output": "buffer",
    "bitrate": 192,
    //"raw": true
});

const micInputStream = micInstance.getAudioStream();
micInputStream.pipe(chunker);
micInstance.start();
chunker.on('data', function(chunk) {
    console.log(chunk);
    console.log(encoder.encode(chunk));
});
```

Error message:

```
[object Uint8Array]
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff ff 00 00 ff ff 00 00 ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 ... 8142 more bytes>
/Users/dfd/Documents/audio.js:53
    console.log(encoder.encode(chunk));
                        ^

**Error: Could not create encoder. Check the encoder parameters
**    at IsSilence.<anonymous> (/Users/dfd/Documents/audio.js:53:25)
    at IsSilence.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at IsSilence._transform (/Users/dfd/node_modules/mic/lib/silenceTransform.js:81:10)
    at Transform._write (node:internal/streams/transform:175:8)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)
    at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10)
```

Node.js v18.14.0

When I changed the sampling freq from 44.1 kHz to 48 kHz in

```
const encoder = new OpusEncoder(44100, 2);
```

The error message is different as follows.

```
[object Uint8Array]
<Buffer 00 00 ff ff ff ff 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 ff ff ff ff 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ... 8142 more bytes>
/Users/dfd/Documents/audio.js:53
    console.log(encoder.encode(chunk));
                        ^

**Error: Cannot create a Buffer larger than 0x100000000 bytes
**    at IsSilence.<anonymous> (/Users/dfd/Documents/audio.js:53:25)
    at IsSilence.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at IsSilence._transform (/Users/dfd/node_modules/mic/lib/silenceTransform.js:81:10)
    at Transform._write (node:internal/streams/transform:175:8)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)
    at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10) {
  code: 'ERR_BUFFER_TOO_LARGE'
}
```

It seems there are not a lot resources online related to the arguments of the function `encode()`. Not sure if it is the type of the buffer/chunk or something else.